# Where to obtain man pages for XLib or X11

Tags: linux, x11, xlib

I am trying to use '**man XCreateGC**', but I get a response; '**No manual entry for XCreateGC**'.
I installed latest libx11-dev and libxkbcommon-x11-dev.
I guess installing these main libs does not install man pages?

Answer (score 4):

The doc package is called `libx11-doc`. (Debian/Ubuntu)

Comment: Just in case anyone needs a list of things they can pass to `man` I found that listing the doc package files was really useful: `dpkg -L libx11-doc`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Linux distribution in particular, what the package is names, and if it's available at all.

You can always find the man pages online at https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/ and the cleaned up HTML version of the Xlib programming manual at https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/